# Does cnosdb support SIMD？

Tags: cnosdb

If vectorized execution is supported, the benefits are as follows:

1. Do the same job with fewer instructions.
2. Execute more CPU instructions in fewer cycles.
3. Compute each query in parallel using multiple threads.
   It is hoped that cnosdb will be able to use the techniques of SIMD